# Get components of a path as array

Tags: ruby

I'd like to get the single components of a path as an array.

I came to these two solutions:

```rb
path = '/usr/share/doc/less/'

parts = path.split(File::Separator)
p parts #  => ["", "usr", "share", "doc", "less"]

require 'pathname'
parts = []
Pathname.new(path).each_filename {|f| parts << f}
p parts #  => ["usr", "share", "doc", "less"]
```

1. `String.split()`

   Is this robust and portable?
2. `Pathname.each_filename()`

   Looks a bit verbose for Ruby. However, this should be portable, right?

Are there better ways? Have I missed something that's standard Ruby?

Comment: You can simply use `...each_filename.to_a` to get your array - there's no need to initialize it beforehand.

Comment: @ZachKemp Thanks for your comment, I always forget to check whether a block is really needed.

Comment: @ArupRakshit How would you do that? I want to transform `/usr/share/doc/less/` to `["usr", "share", "doc", "less"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's spot on. `Pathname` is part of ruby's standard library, and it should be an entirely portable solution.

You can just use this:

```
Pathname.new(path).each_filename.to_a
```

Or even:

```
Pathname(path).each_filename.to_a
```

Comment: Great. I had a strange feeling that there must be shortcut. I always forget that these iterators don't necessarily need a block but return something instead.

Comment: @JoshLee It works for me in 1.9. After the answers here, I've looked up the source in the doc, it's `return to_enum(__method__) unless block_given?`

Comment: @Scolytus, what's happening here is that each_filename is returning an  enumerator, and enumerators can be used to do all kinds of things (you could say `Pathname(path).each_filename.map { }` etc. Enumerators can usually be flattened to arrays as well.